# Default login to rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm using devise gem for login functionality in my Rails3 application.The gem as provides functionality for login along with sign up & sign out.I  want to change this functionality and implement a default login only for the admin with no sign up.I cannot figure out what changes to be made..Do reply if any queries..

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable sign_up you should be able to just not pass the `:registerable` parameter to the `devise` method in your User model.

```
class User < ActiveModel::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable #, :registerable
end
```